# Data types match, but I still get an error with my Linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

So I am getting this:

> Error: Argument of type `"Person *"` is incompatible with type `"Person *"`

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  Im sure it is something stupid but if someone could point it out that would be great.

```
LL* g_list;
int size = 50;

char getOption();

int main()
{
    char input;
    bool running = true;
    g_list = new LL;

    char* name = new char[size];
    char* color = new char[size];
    cout << "enter name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "enter color: ";
    cin >> color;
    Person* pers = new Person(name, color);

    g_list->addBack(pers);  //error

    return 0;
}

//LL.cpp file (linked list)
void LL::addBack(Person* pobj)
{
    if (count_ == 0)
    {
        head_ = pobj;
    }
    else 
    {
        Person* ptr = head_;
        for (int i = 0; i < count_ - 1; i++)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next_;
        }

        ptr->next_ = pobj;
    }

    count_++;
    pobj->next_ = 0;

    return;
}

//Person constructor
Person::Person(char* name, char* color)
{
    name_ = new char[strlen(name)];
    strcpy(name_, name);

    color_ = new char[strlen(color)];
    strcpy(color_, color);

    next_ = 0;
}
```

Let me know if any more info is needed.

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using string ?

Comment: Your code fragment is both too long and too short. It contains lots of material that could be removed, and would still reproduce your error. Also, it is missing key material which would allow us to compile it. Please reduce your program to the *smallest*, *complete* program that still has the error (hint: it should be about 15-20 lines long). Copy-paste that **entire** program into your question. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: You're not including headers correctly, or haven't written a separate header file correctly. Also, note that what you've written is *very* far from real C++.

Answer (score 2):

It seems weird as the types are reportedly the same.  I can think of only one reason: you have two different `Person` types and they are conflicting.  You need to figure out from where the definition of `Person` in `main()` is coming and compare that to the definition of `Person` used in `LL::addBack()`

Comment: As, for example, you might have forward-declared `class Person;` inside the `LL` class?